# Can not install the ngx-translate/core, Here is my error log. (Ionic 4 and Angular 7.x)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4, ngx-translate

Here is my npm error log

[image]

and my npm version :`npm@6.7.0`
node version:`node@v10.15.0`

Comment: hey, this problem has been solved by change the npm registry：
npm config set registry http://registry.npm.taobao.org/